# Can multiple C# apps use one App.Config file?

Tags: c#, .net

We have many C# console apps that run on scheduled tasks.  All of these apps have their own config file, which contain settings like our smtp server.  If our smtp server ever changed, we would have to manually go into each config file and change it.  Can multiple apps look at 1 config file on the C: drive, or is that considered bad practice?  Using the database to store values is a no no.

Comment: Why is using a database a no-no?  This is a pretty common practice.

Comment: Our admins might not have DB access.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can point to external config files inside your application's configuration file like the following, and have all your applications use the same set of settings from a single file:

```
<appSettings file="c:\CommonSettings.config">
   <add key="MyKey" value="12"/> 
</appSettings>
```

For more information, you can read following articles:

- [AppSettings can Reference an External Config File](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2003/04/09/5261.aspx)
- [How to share custom application configuration settings across projects in .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20150312232725/http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555396)

Answer (score 3):

It is not directly possible to share one application configuration file because the `.config` filename needs to match the executable name (so for `example.exe` it would be `example.exe.config`).

It makes sense to have *separate* values for the different applications, as they are separate applications.

If there are configuration sections that you do want to share, you can use the [`configSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) attribute to point to a file. The `appSettings` section also has a specific `file` attribute that you can use in the same manner.

If there are certain configuration values that *are* shared across all applications, you can consider placing them in the [`machine.config`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx) file for the version of the framework you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use custom xml files to store configuration data ?
There's no necessity to use app.config.

Comment: I can use xml files.  I was thinking this might be easier anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cinchoo framework you can achieve this, by simply creating custom configuration object and use it all the console applications. All of them will read from same configuration file. For more information, please visit http://www.cinchoo.com