# Which is the better storage to keep similar configuration for multiple application?

Tags: c#, database, api, config, system-variable

I have multiple application on same server [Websites,API's etc]. For these I have used app.config/web.config files respectively. But managing these files required manual intervention which is quite risky due to their syntax.

I have suggested to use database to store config , but I think it will be expensive calls,as server will hit for numerous requests.

Can I use system variables to achieve this?
Please suggest better way to accomplish this.

Comment: required manual intervention --- then use tested scripts to modify?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly database call is costly, instead of that place a centralized config file  that can be reached by all projects. I am doing the same in my project like more than 50 projetcs(Windows Service, Windows Forms, Web Service, WebSite, MVC app) all referring a single config.

refer this [Common app config for multiple applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181969/common-app-config-for-multiple-applications) It may help you

Comment: Suggestion is good but issues with maintenance.Common config file for multiple application will increase number of appsettings <key,value> pairs n too conflicts , like due to manual changes key with name DefaultLanguageCode also can be added as Defaultlanguage with same value,which is duplicate.

Comment: I am using the following <applicationSettings>
    <ImagingServer.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Timeout" serializeAs="String">
        <value>00:00:30</value>
      </setting>
    </ImagingServer.Properties.Settings>
 <Transport.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Timeout" serializeAs="String">
        <value>00:00:60</value>
      </setting>
    </Transport.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>

Comment: Can I use system variables to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate XML files to store settings , These files can be stored in project directory or either in a centralized repository. XML manipulation is so easy and server overhead is also very low .

Setting can be stored in XML files as key val