# writing and linking to a common config file

Tags: c#, config

I have a console app project that write some info to a common.app.config file which other library project will read from in runtime. The writing operation is as follows:

```cs
var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap
{
    ExeConfigFilename = @"C:\CONSOLE_APP_PROJECT_PATH\common.app.config"
};

var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("FullLogPath",combinedPath);
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal,true);
                        
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Thw writing operation is done. To access this common.app.config file, I tried the procedures in this link :

[Reuse config values across projects](https://github.com/reyronald/AppSettingsOverhaul)

I have added the common.app.config file from the other library project **as link** to avoid copying. So whatever that is written in runtime will be reflected in the linked common.app.config file .After linking from other project , the .cproj file has the following update:

```
<Content Include="..\..\DiagnosticsServiceHost\common.app.config">
  <Link>common.app.config</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

The project that refers the common config has its own configuration file (App.config) and inside it I have made the following changes:

```
<appSettings file=".\bin\x86\Debug\common.app.config">

</appSettings>
```

But I cannot access the value of the key - FullLogPath in runtime from common.app.config with following snippet: (the value of FullLogPath is null)

```
public class AppSettingsParent
{
    protected AppSettingsParent()
    {
    }

    // Only meant to be used in testing environments
    private static AppSettingsSection AppSettingsSection { get; } = null;

    protected static string Get([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (AppSettingsSection != null)
        {
            return AppSettingsSection.Settings[propertyName].Value;
        }

        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[propertyName];
    }
}


public class CommonAppSettings : AppSettingsParent
{
    private CommonAppSettings()
    {
    }
    
    public static string FullLogPath => Get();

}

 private static string InitLogFile(string ecu, string filename)
    {
        var folder = Path.Combine(CommonAppSettings.FullLogPath + alu + "\\");

        var absoluteFilePath = Path.Combine(folder.Trim(), filename.Trim() + "-" + alu.Trim() + ".log");

        return absoluteFilePath;
    }
```

Comment: The config file should be in same folder as the dll.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181969/common-app-config-for-multiple-applications

Comment: Does it mean that even the linked config file can be opened in the same manner with OpenMappedExeConfiguration ?

Comment: Are you asking about multiple project in the same application sharing configuration, or different applications sharing a config file?

Comment: Multiple projects under one solution sharing common.app.config file

Comment: Sharing a readonly file is easy with a link. But debugging in VS, each project will execute in their own build folder. Maybe you should ensure all your debug launch profiles have the same current directory.